# contact page with some texts, a form & google map

Tags: 7, google-maps, emails

I would like to have contact page which displays information about address, phone, email and some texts. + a contact form + a Google map showing location. 
Please let me know how the above is achieved. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use webforms to create your contact form. Make sure to use the option of creating the webform in a block. Create two more blocks. One containing the address and contact and the other containing your map.

And using like panels or a page. arrange your blocks on that page.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I add blocks in contact page? (I have created a page using add content>> basic page)

Comment: Is the contact page a page you created yourself, or the default contact page?

Comment: the contact page created to show contact details in text format. Add content>>Basic page in admin interface.

Comment: There are two ways of adding blocks in drupal. Either you use the default blocks module or the context module. To add a block simply go to admin/structure/block/add and then create a new block with your content. On the page tab below the body textarea, choose the radio button only the listed page. And in the text area below it, put the url of the contact page you created. Click save. Once that is done it should take you back to the default page showing you a list of your blocks. Then using the drop down list select where to place the block. And click save.